# Capture body content in Mako?

Tags: python, mako

Is it possible to get the rendered body content from within a Mako template? What I mean is that I can display the body using `${self.body()}`, but what if I want to do something to it first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently what I was looking for is the [`capture` function](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/filtering.html#buffering). From the docs:

> The other way to buffer the output of a def or any Mako callable is by
>   using the built-in capture function. This function performs an
>   operation similar to the above buffering operation except it is
>   specified by the caller.

```
${" results " + capture(somedef) + " more results "}
```

Or in my case:

```
<%
    body = capture(self.body)
    # etc.
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to pass it through a custom defined filter

```
<%
    def myFilter(txt): 
        return "whatever I want to do it"
>%

${self.body() | myFilter}
```